# Limit Excel macro output to cells with content

Tags: excel, vba

I have just begun using macros in Excel, so I know nothing about it.
This is the macro I'm using, which creates files named after the cells in the A column.
The cells themselves are filled by the content of other cells from the B to the F columns.

```
Sub Titles()
    Dim xSh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xSh In Worksheets
        xSh.Select
        Call RunCode
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub RunCode()
    'your code here
Const forReading = 1, forAppending = 3, fsoForWriting = 2
Dim fs, objTextStream, sText As String
Dim lLastRow As Long, lRowLoop As Long, lLastCol As Long, lColLoop As Long

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For lRowLoop = 1 To lLastRow

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextStream = fs.opentextfile("C:\Temp\Titles\" & Cells(lRowLoop, 1) & ".title", fsoForWriting, True)

    sText = ""

    For lColLoop = 1 To 7
        sText = sText & Cells(lRowLoop, lColLoop) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
    Next lColLoop

    objTextStream.writeline (Left(sText, Len(sText) - 1))


    objTextStream.Close
    Set objTextStream = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

Next lRowLoop

End Sub
```

The macro is working just fine, but I would like to make one adjustment, which is to not create a file if  the correspondent cell in the F column is empty, (B to E are always filled).

I hope I explained myself correctly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(lRowLoop, "F").Value) Then`...

Comment: Thank you. Where should place it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `IsEmpty` to check if the cell is empty.
2. `Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` should be outside the loop.
3. `Set fs = Nothing` should be outside the loop or eliminated.

```vb
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For lRowLoop = 1 To lLastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(lRowLoop, "F").Value) Then
        Set objTextStream = fs.opentextfile("C:\Temp\Titles\" & Cells(lRowLoop, 1) & ".title", fsoForWriting, True)

        sText = ""

        For lColLoop = 1 To 7
            sText = sText & Cells(lRowLoop, lColLoop) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
        Next lColLoop

        objTextStream.writeline Left(sText, Len(sText) - 1)
        objTextStream.Close

        Set objTextStream = Nothing
    End If
Next lRowLoop

Set fs = Nothing
```

<sub>N.B. Untested as of posting</sub>

Comment: So the cells in column F are populated? Step through with F8 to see this in execution.

Comment: Yes, some are populated.
Stepping through F8 I can see that it goes from `For lRowLoop = 1` to `lLastRow to Set fs = Nothing`, skipping everything in between.

Comment: Do you still have `lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` prior to the loop?

Comment: No, I don't have it.

Comment: Please put it back in.

Comment: Seems like you have an issue with your path then.

Comment: What else could the problem be?